# Why doesn't "marks < max(marks)" work

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to know the working of the group queries

Suppose there is a table Student(id,name,marks)

Now if i want to output all the students except those/that who scored highest, why this query does not work ?

```
SELECT * FROM Students
WHERE marks < MAX(marks)
```

but this works fine

```
SELECT * FROM Students
WHERE marks < (SELECT MAX(marks) FROM Students)
```

EDIT:
Please don't suggest different ways to work this out, I know already.
My question is WHY THIS DOES NOT WORK, please see the title closely

Comment: Use HAVING instead of WHERE.  You need post-aggregation filtering.

Comment: Why are you trying to just list all the students that do not have the top mark? (i.e. usually all the class except one or maybe two)

Comment: actually i was asked to get the second highest marks,
so i tried
SELECT * FROM Students
WHERE marks < MAX(marks)
ORDER BY marks desc
LIMIT 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that that's how SQL is designed. The longer answer requires us to look at what your first query means and why that ultimately doesn't quite make sense.

One could imagine an SQL where you can compare an aggregate for the whole table against a row value. However, what if you had a `GROUP BY`? Would your `MAX` be for the entire table or just for the group? What if you wanted it to be against a different grouping, or for the whole table instead of for the group?

Now let's think about it in terms of underlying operations. To actually compute the row values and the max, the database engine has to do two operations: one to find the max, and then another to scan the table, comparing values to this computed max. In your `WHERE` clause, without subqueries, however, you are simply comparing values from columns on a row-by-row basis. Adding in an aggregate is a different kind of data, which cannot be gathered by looking at values on a row-by-row basis.

Another way to look at it is this: aggregation happens AFTER a `GROUP BY` (even if the `GROUP BY` is implicit). But the `WHERE` clause executes before the `GROUP BY`. So it can't access aggregates.

For all those reasons, and probably more, SQL was designed to force you to be explicit when comparing values of different kinds. You have to tell it that you are explicitly computing a maximum and then using that to compare against row values. This is done with the subquery.

Comment: Thanks, perfect explanation. +1

Comment: Yet another way to look at it: `WHERE` clauses behave like they're evaluated individually for each row. In this context, `MAX(marks)` is the maximum of a single value (the value of `marks` for that row!), so the condition is never true.